# Reading an hidden input field from form of a different PHP site

Tags: php

I have the following hidden input in a form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
```

I am posting this input value to another PHP page for processing through a form, however, when I try to read the value of the input field using `$_POST["token"]`, I find it empty. I looked all over the Internet for a solution, but the only one I found is to place everything into one page (the form together with the processing code); but I want the processing code to be in a separate page.

This is the markup:

```
<form id="registerform" name="registerform" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
</form>
```

The problem here is that I can read the values of the first name and last name. but the value of the hidden input is not accessible.

Comment: Do you have your `<input>` field in a form or do you submit it with XHR/Ajax? Could you share this markup/code? Did you check the network console in the DevTools? There, you can see, if the token value was submitted correctly.

Comment: no I didn't check the network console in the DevTools, i missed this bit. but i will do right now

Comment: yeah, i can see it there, but I still can't read it

Comment: So, if you change `<input type="hidden" />` to `<input type="text" />`, you can see the correct value in the input field and the input field is then also in the devtools sent to the next page (no matter what type)? That should work this way. Is the value inside of the output of `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`?

Comment: yes it is inside of the output

Comment: If it is inside the output of `print_r($_POST)`, you actually get it via POST. This command shows you all data you got via POST. So, if it is in there, you can definitely access it via the printed key. If the output contains `[token] => "123"` → you can access it with `$_POST['token']`

Comment: have you check to ensure $token isn't empty in<?php echo $token; ?>

Comment: @SML no I echoed it and it is there, I also checked it int the devTools.

Comment: @ ssc-hrep3, thanks a lot for your support, finally got it working; it was a stupid TYPO

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 perhaps you should write all the debugging steps in an answer. I didn't know that it is possible to check from the network console until reading your comment a minute ago

Comment: Thanks any way, it was actually a typing mistake in the ajax code

Comment: @SML I posted a step-by-step debug guideline for the problem. Would be nice, if you could accept it, Adam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is correct. If it won't work like this, you probably made some typo or mistake and need to debug your code. Here is one way to do that.

1. Check if the value `$token` is correctly rendered into the `<input>`. Does it have a value in the PHP script or is already empty there? If it is not empty in the PHP script (you can `echo` it out, to see its value), you need to check the rendered HTML. Does it have any mistakes? It's best to just open the `view-source` tab to see what PHP actually renders. Somewhere in the rendered HTML, there needs to be a hidden input field with the value set to the same as in the PHP script. Check also the syntax.
2. If `1` did not yet resolve your problem, you can try to send the form and observe the request in the DevTools of your browser (it's probably best to use Firefox or Chrome for that). To see the request, you should open the DevTools (push `F12`) and switch to the Network tab. Make sure, you hit `Preserve log` to keep the logs on the page switch. Click on the row of the page where your data should have been sent to. You can see the parameters on the bottom of the details. Your hidden parameter needs to be there, if not, you are not correctly sending it to the PHP script. → Go back to step 1.
3. If the error still resists, enter the following line on top of the PHP page where your form is sent to (the page you have in the `action` attribute of the form): `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`. This will print out all data which is received by the PHP script via POST (change it to `$_GET`, if you are expecting GET data). Submit your form. If the `token` key is present on the next page (e.g. `[token] => "123"` is part of the output), you can definitely access it via `$_POST['token']`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help